# CDialog *m_pages[6]; vs CDialog *m_pages = new CDialog[6];?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Not sure why I can't take CDialog and set the memory space in the cpp file.  It only works in the header file.   Isn't this the same thing???  thanks

---

Header file:

```
public:
    CDialog *m_pages[6];  // this works
```

---

Header file:

```
CDialog *m_pages;
```

cpp file

```
m_pages = new CDialog[6];  //this fails
```

---

After seeing what I did wrong(1st poster: "creating an array of six pointers to CDialog").
This is what I missed: (and now it works!)

```
CDialog **m_pages = new CDialog*[6]; //double pointer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zkyyhxw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). CDialogs require at least one parameter in their constructor, that's why you can't allocate them in your second example, since they don't have a default constructor.

In your first example, you're creating an array of six pointers to `CDialog`. That is completely different from an array of six `CDialog`, which is what you are trying to allocate in the second one.

Comment: If I want to adjust the number at run-time:( 6 -> 10), how do I do this then? thx

Comment: Use `std::vector`s or other STL containers.

Answer (score 1):

Those decls are very different: this `CDialog *m_pages[6];` is an array of 6 *pointers* to CDialog, while `m_pages = new CDialog[6];` it's an array of 6 CDialog.

To use the second declaration, I think you could do something like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Object  {
    Object(int id) : id(id) {}
    int id;
};

void main_construct_vector()
{
    Object *a = new Object[2] {Object(1), Object(2)};
    cout << a[0].id << ' ' << a[1].id << endl;
}
```

That code output as expected

```
1 2
```

Definitely, this is not the usual way to go...